# Full width header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my header full width but I don't know why it doesn't work, the high is perfect but I don't know what's wrong with the width,
I would appreciate it if you can help me, this is what I have tried:

```
#header {
  width:100%;
 -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-bottom: 9%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Put your `html` code as well.

Comment: html code??? you must be missing something

Comment: the header part:  <header id="header" class="hoc clear">  </header>

Answer (score 0):

I have made a demo for you and corrected your code.
Do check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/djmayank/qsmpbs9d/

HTML:

```
<div id= "header">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
  background-color: red;
  height:5px;
  width:100%;
 -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-bottom: 9%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I did use what you wrote but it didn't work, My div looks like this:   <header id="header" class="hoc clear">  </header>

Comment: still the same :( I'm using an image so I don't know if the problem is from that?

Comment: are you using bootstrap? or better share your code, something must be overriding , either some display :flex; or some position.

Comment: you definitely used display:flex somewhere?

Comment: Yes I'm using boostarp, and notI'm not using display:flex . The header used to work perfectly but I changed the image and then it didn't work

Comment: yup bootstrap have done this , use  !important in front of all css code

Comment: I tried to use important for each line of the header like this:   width:100% !important; but still the same it didn't change

Comment: I did share the html and css part of the header

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your browser is adding default css to your project which adds padding/margins to things as well as other stuff. I usually put `resets` at the top of my css file which clears all the default css. A popular css reset that alot of people use is erics reset:

Place this at the top of your css file and your header should be full width

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did use what you wrote but it didn't work, My div looks like this:   <header id="header" class="hoc clear">  </header>